# How to interpret a 'noisy' Python FFT?

Tags: fft

The following is a plot of the FFT of a noisy electronic component. It's not white noise, but is stochastic in nature.  I used Python's matplotlib `plt.magnitude_spectrum(...)` function. It was a 1MHz sample rate.

[image: fft]

What is the actual magnitude?  Is it the top or the bottom of the purple? Or am I supposed to interpolate a mean through the middle?  Or something else?

Comment: "FFT of a noisy component": um, I'd presume that's the FFT of a sampled voltage or current over or through that component, right? Can you define what you mean with "actual magnitude"? We don't really know what you're supposed to do, because we neither really know what we're looking at, nor what you really want, nor what you want to do with the result afterwards! Application context might really massively help here :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Oh sorry.  It's nothing complicated.  I'm just wondering which part of an FFT you  read. I'm unfamiliar with the Python implementation. Do you just fit a line through the middle of the purple? I'd like to be able to summarise it as eg. rolls off at 20dB/decade , or something...

Comment: The problem is that what you're showing us is a "crunched together" graph, and very far from the output of an FFT.  So, you do neither, because as said, what you do is dictated by what you need, and you still haven't told us!

Comment: It's a log frequency plot so not as intuitive to look at. But if you take the direct FFT output and multiply it by the complex conjugate of itself you can get a power estimate per bin. You can then do various moving averages to access the average power across bins. Do not average the log magnitude output as that has other errors depending on the noise distribution from a true rms power.

Comment: @DanBoschen Okay thanks.  I think that I've understood.  The data is only 8 bit, so the FFT is full of quantization noise riding atop the signal.

Comment: Yes that quantization noise itself would be reasonably approximated as white noise (spreading evenly across your complete frequency space) assuming your signal and the sampling clock are uncorrelated. The total integrated noise power would be approximately 50 dB below a full-scale sine-wave (just before clipping), assuming you have a full 8 bits effectively (ENOB).

Comment: The key phrase I think you're looking for is "power spectral density"

Comment: @TimWescott Okay, but it's really not.  There's no power at all, it's simply voltage readings on an oscilloscope.  This is the FFT of a Zener diode in avalanche as an entropy source for cryptography.  My question concerns how I might summarise my wacko graph.

Comment: If it makes you feel better call it "volt-squared spectral density" in your head, or "spectral density of the autocorrelation expectation value".  But it's still called "power spectral density" in the literature, even though it's used in a lot of places where the word "power" has no physical meaning.  The method suggested by @DanBoschen is one quick way of getting an estimate of PSD.

Comment: @TimWescott And if this was a legal answer, much points would befall you :)